# Combine rows of two tabel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this:

```
Name          Index1           Name        Index2
Muster1          1             Muster1      10
Muster2          2             Muster3      20
```

I would like to have summary of these two tables, something like this:

```
    Name        Index1     Index2
  Muster1          1         10
  Muster2          2        NULL
  Muster3         NULL      20
```

How can I do it in SQL?

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part. What have you researched, tried to code, and found to not work?

Comment: The problem is, that I dont know what should I research? wich SQL command do that

Answer (score 4):

A simple `FULL JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.Name,t2.Name) Name,
       t1.Index1,
       t2.Index2
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
FULL JOIN dbo.Table2 t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name
;
```

Comment: Quick and simple :-)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This would return the desired results the OP stated they want.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah, not sure either, but I've learned to not ask about them :). Thanks

Comment: Most of those people who don't comment why it is downvoted don't bother to offer an explanation. Myself I don't like to downvote when something is bad, instead I try to offer a suggestion to make it worthy of an upvote. Oh well....such is SO and the point system.

Comment: @SeanLange It was (_probably_) downvoted because it doesn't actually offer an explanation of how to set up the query, how it works, _why_ it works, etc. It's essentially a "code only" answer, which are frequently frowned upon here, as explaining the answer will do more for future readers. BTW, not my downvote.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yeah, that may be it

Comment: Downvote was accidental by me. I simply can't undo it unless you edit the answer. Although I do agree with @GrumpyCrouton, it would be nice to see an explanation rather than just a code snippet

Comment: Also there are many ways to do this. Why is this preferred over others?